# ¿En glassfish 4.1 existe alguna cache o algo que impida que, cuando hago un cambio de una aplicación, no se reflejen los cambios?

Tags: java, glassfish

Estoy utilizando GlassFIsh Server Open Source Edition 4.1

El problema es el siguiente. Cada vez que hago un redeploy o incluso un deploy de una aplicación (osea, nueva o existente), los cambios que haga no se ven reflejados.

Esto me lleva a pensar a que por algun lado existe una cache que debo refrescar o borrar.

Por ejemplo, tengo una aplicación que tiene un navBar, al cual le quite 2 elementos de él, y al hacer el redeploy con el nuevo WAR, sigue saliendo igual, o por ejemplo, quite un link de un elemento del navBar, dicho link anteriormente apuntaba a (por ejemplo) google.com, luego lo cambie a duckduckgo.com, por lo cual en TODO el proyecto dejo de existir la palabra o string "google", aun así, cuando hize el redeploy, el link seguía apuntando a google.com

Realmente no me lo explico.

Cualquier ayuda o guía será de gran ayuda.

**Nota: Los cambios no se reflejan en ninguna máquina, no hablo solamente de mi localhost. Incluso ya borre la cache del navegador.**

**Nota 2: He hecho lo que mencionan ambos Ventur y Jorgesys, y no, sigo sin poder hacer el deploy actualizado, realmente no entiendo porque, tengo código que no debeira salir comentado y aun asi aparece, borre todas las carpetas dentro del directorio domain1, que hace referencia a dicha aplicación y no.**

Comment: Si existen datos temporales en GlassFIsh o en cualquier otro servidor, pero por lo que mencionas seria suficiente con limpiar la cache del navegador. Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Ahora que lo mencionas... Nunca he borrado esa cache (aunque siempre uso ctrl + F5)... intentare para descartar. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Ya intente incluso borrando las carpetas generated, osgi-cache y aplications, y nomas no.

Comment: el redeploy lo haces con el comando o a través de la consola de administración de GlassFish?

Comment: a travez del GUI de glassfish, se me carga en localhost:4848

Comment: Intenta usando la opcion clean and build, despues de eso carga nuevamente el war generado. Limpia nuevamente las caches del servidor, esto debe hacerse estando detenido, y tambien limpia la cache del navegador,

Comment: @JoséHerreraAvila que IDE usas para el deploy, la caché del navegador no soluciona este problema, en realidad debes elimnar la caché del server.

Comment: @Jorgesys Justo ese es el problema que creo tener Jorge. No se como borrar la cache del server. Borre las carpetas generated, osgi-cache y applications, y volvi a hacer el deploy, y no funionó.

Comment: @JoséHerreraAvila antes de eliminar /osgi-cache y  /autodeploy debes detener el servidor, posteriormente al borrarlos iniciarlo de nuevo, esto funciona?

Comment: Asi lo hize siempre y no... Justo acabo de descubir porque fue el problema. Resulta que el netbeans, por alguna razon, cuando le doy build o cleanAndBuild, los archivos compilados que van en WebPages/WEB-INF, no se estaban regenerando, por ende, por mas cambios que le hiciera, esos no se reescribian y el war terminaba teniendo los mismos cambios (o no cambios).

Comment: Igual podría ser relevante si despliegas en modo comprimido o explotado (una carpeta en vez de un .war), puedes verificarlo fácilmente accediendo a las carpetas de tu servidor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final el problema fue que la carpeta de WEB-INF no se estaba regenerando, elimine su contenido y ya se comenzo a regenerar. Problema solucionado.

Answer (score 6):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> Los cambios no se reflejan en ninguna máquina, no hablo solamente de
>   mi localhost. Incluso ya borre la cache del navegador.

El problema no se debe al caché de tu navegador, esta relacionado a que ya existe una versión de la aplicación en el `GlassFish` Server, algo al parecer común usando la versión 4.1.

Ocurre cuando ya existe una aplicación implementada previamente en el servidor `GlassFish`, elimina el contenido de `/autodeploy/`:

Suponiendo que usas el dominio default "domain1"

• Deten el servidor:

```
stop-domain domain1
```

• Elimina el contenido de los directorios.

```
/domain1/autodeploy/
/domain1/osgi-cache/
```

• Inicia nuevamente el servidor

```
start-domain domain1
```

Considera actualizar a GlassFish 5.0 por lo cual debes usar Java 8 aquí ya no se presenta este problema.

Answer (score 3):

complementando la respuesta de @JorgeSys ,
Valida que no exista una versión previa dentro de : 
\domains\domain1\ **applications** \

Si usas eclipse  para despliegue valida de igual forma:
\domains\domain1\ **eclipseApps** \

Y por ultimo   puedes probar lo siguiente : inicia tu servidor(sin deployar la aplicación), ve a la consola administrativa de  glassFish,y en **nodes/ Applications**, checa que no este desplegada tu app, ya que en lo personal me paso que a pesar de haber borrado las carpetas antes mencionadas, por alguna razón Glashfish no destruía el despliegue anterior.

Espero esto sea de tu ayuda.

Saludos